# Rails app with 2 domains: Define 2 SMTP's in initializers/devise.rb & environments/development.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Rails app that handles two domains. The app is set up like described in [this blogpost](http://www.nicolasgarnil.me/blog/2013/handling-multiple-domains-routes-in-ruby-on-rails/). In my controllers and views I am using `request.domain` to determine which app a visitor visits.

When someone signs up for an account, Devise sends out a confirmation email. This process depends on the following lines:

```
# config/environments/development.rb

MyApp::Application.configure do
  ...
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :port                 => 587,
    :domain               => 'localhost',
    :user_name            => 'my@email.com',
    :password             => 'MyPassword',
    :authentication       => 'plain',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
  ...
end

# config/initializers/devise.rb

Devise.setup do |config|
  ...
  # ==> Mailer Configuration
  # Configure the e-mail address which will be shown in Devise::Mailer,
  # note that it will be overwritten if you use your own mailer class with default "from" parameter.
  config.mailer_sender = "my@email.com"
  ...
end
```

I need the `:username`in `development.rb` and the `config.mailer_sender` in `devise.rb` to depend on `request.domain`, because the user should of course receive an email from the domain he signs up for.

Answer (score 0):

I use `SiteSetting` model to specify different mailboxes for each `Site`
`SiteSetting` contains configs for each mailboxes.
A code for mailer is:

```
# app/mailers/invitation_mailer.rb
class InvitationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def invitation(invitation)
    @site = invitation.site
    @invitation = invitation
    email_settings = @site.email_settings.first

    mail(to: invitation.email,
         from: email_settings.try(:from) || 'notifier@example.com',
         subject: "Invitation",
         delivery_method_options: delivery_options(email_settings))
  end
  private

    def delivery_options(email_settings)
       @_delivery_options ||= 
         if email_settings
           {
             address:              email_settings.address,
             port:                 email_settings.port,
             domain:               email_settings.domain,
             user_name:            email_settings.user_name,
             password:             email_settings.password,
             authentication:       email_settings.authentication,
             enable_starttls_auto: email_settings.enable_startls_auto
           }
         else
           {
             address:              'smtp.google.com',
             port:                 587,
             domain:               'example.com',
             user_name:            'notifier@example.com',
             password:             'secret',
             authentication:       'plain',
             enable_starttls_auto: true
           }
         end
    end

end
```

### Update

You can pass `username` like `invitation` in this examle 
and then you can get acsess to `username` in your `Mailer` class (for example `InvitationMailer`)

```
# app/controller/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def invitation
    invitation = Invitation.find(params[:invitation_id])
    InvitationMailer.invitation(invitation).deliver
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I am not that I understand how to connect this method to the flow that Devise currently handles. At which point do I trigger the `invite` method? And how do I get `request.domain` into the arguments of the `invitation" method (which I suppose is necessary in order to determine which domain settings to use)?

Comment: Hi. Are you using Devise for authentication? Because as far as I see this would disable Devise from the process. I am not quite sure exactly how Devise handles emailing, but I would imagine that I need to override that method.

Comment: in `development.rb` you specifies just a default setting, you can not use them ever. Just override exsisting devise mailer method with yours.

Comment: Hi. I have now created a custom Mailer as described in [this post](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-custom-mailer). But when override with the line `opts[:from] = 'my@email.com'` the confirmation email still comes from the address specified in `development.rb`.